# what does that in ActionScript 3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe

Hi Does any one tell me what is `[Event(name="change", type="flash.events.Event")]` this?

I'm using ActionScript 3.0 in Adobe Flash IDE.

Answer (score 3):

In Flash Builder, the metadata is used for ASDocs and code hinting.  It means that the component/class which has that data may dispatch an event named "Change" which has class type of "flash.events.Event".

It could be considered a developer helper.  It isn't required, but it makes things a bit easier for other developers using your class.

[More info on Metadata](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html).

I couldn't find any metadata tag documentation on Flash Pro or AS3.  But, here is a [blog post](http://www.boostworthy.com/blog/?p=157) that covers some stuff.

Comment: In addition to this, Event metadata will appear as events which can be handled when adding components in MXML.  So If the component you build has a "change" event described in a metadata tag, in MXML you can directly add "change=<handler>" to the component's element.

Comment: @bedwyr I call that "Code Hinting" and referenced it in the first sentence of my answer. But, thank you for the more detailed explanation.

Comment: @Flextrax, I didn't notice your code-hinting statement, sorry :)

Comment: @Flextrax What Event metadata does is a little bit more than just code hinting. "Use the [Event] metadata tag to define the MXML property for an event and the data type of the event object that a component emits" from http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html

Comment: @Flextras Because if you don't use the Event metadata to define your custom property for the event, when you'll write myCustomEvent="doSomething" in the MXML you'll get a phat error. That's why. Code hinting implies that the property already exists, where in this case it really doesn't until you define it with the metadata.

Comment: @bug-a-lot It is true that you'll get a compiler error if you reference an event in MXML that is not defined in metadata.  Events are very different than properties, and defining the event metadata does not create a property on your component.  It does allow that event to show up in MXML code hinting, though.  I guess you could say that the compiler also uses it to validate MXML.

Comment: @Flextras "Use the [Event] metadata tag to define the MXML property for an event and the data type of the event object that a component emits". That's from the livedocs. Admittedly you can't reference that MXML property from actionscript, but it's nevertheless a property. I'm just saying it would be _only_ "code hinting" if you could reference the event in MXML without using the [Event] metadata to define the MXML property. Then again I see code hinting as a feature of the IDE. I could be writing code in notepad, for all you know, but I'd still have to use the [Event] metadata.